# obtaining random sample from a randomly generated dataframe in a dynamic way (not hard-coded)

Tags: python, dataframe, random

I've written some code that will generate a dataframe of randomly generated indices (500 rows).  However, the task is to obtain 5 randomly selected rows ONLY from the last 50 rows (from the randomly generated dataframe).  I've managed to select 5 rows but the problem is that they are not specifically from the last 50 indices of the dataframe as required.  Plus, you cannot use hard-coding.

I have tried the following code which should select 5 rows only from the last 50 rows of the dataframe:

```
def randomly_generated_dataframe(self, df1, select=5, start_range=50, end_range=1):

   selected_indices = np.random.random_integers(len(df1.index[-start_range:]), len(df1.index[:-end_range]), select)
   return df1.loc[selected_indices]
```

I don't get any error message as such but the output is incorrect since the 5 selected rows seem to come from any part of the `dataframe` and not just from the last 50 rows as intended.

Comment: Everything about your question is clear except for hardcoding. Are the 5 and 50 allowed to be hardcoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you wish to select rows *without* replacement, hence `replace=False`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 2)))
df.columns = ['x', 'y']
indices = np.random.choice(df.index[-50:], size=5, replace=False)
result = df.loc[indices]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
     x  y
963  9  8
988  6  3
986  6  3
990  9  5
955  1  2
```